# Dropdown lists in a repeater are all updating to the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, repeater

In short: All the Dropdown lists in a repeater are all updating to the same value.

I have a repeater. Each item contains another repeater which displays multiple users and their charges & preferred currency.

[image]

In the `repeater_ItemDataBound` event, I find and populate the txtcurrency, The image shows that these differ from user to user.
I also populate the ddlPreferredCurrency dropdown list and then select the appropriate value.

The problem is - that whatever the last user's currency is set to, all the DropDownLists change to that value, not just the current one.

Strangely, the currency TextBoxes hold their separate values, but the ListItems of each DropDownList seem to be related... Help ??

Here's my `repeater_ItemDataBound` event:

```
protected void rptrLinkedUsers_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            lnk_User_Pxx lup = (lnk_User_Pxx)e.Item.DataItem;

            DropDownList ddlPreferredCurrency = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlPreferredCurrency");

            foreach (ListItem li in countries)
            {
                ListItem ddli = new ListItem();
                ddli.Text = li.Text;
                ddli.Value = li.Value;
                ddlPreferredCurrency.Items.Add(li);
            }


            if (lup != null && lup.PreferredCurrencyID != null && lup.PreferredCurrencyID != 0)
            {
                ListItem selectedListItem = ddlPreferredCurrency.Items.FindByValue(lup.PreferredCurrencyID.ToString());

                ddlPreferredCurrency.ClearSelection();
                selectedListItem.Selected = true;
            }

        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding the wrong item to your drop down list.

```
ddlPreferredCurrency.Items.Add(li);
```

should be

```
ddlPreferredCurrency.Items.Add(ddli);
```

Comment: This is a great example of how much I love this site... I'm a developer working on my own, and without a fresh pair of eyes, you can look at code again and again and miss the simplest of things - Thank you so much !!